# Reverse engineering Nextbike API and random 16 character pre-shared key

Tags: hash-functions, api

I am trying to get to know how Nextbike's API works. It's not a public API but capturing the outgoing traffic with my phone I can see all the traffic and endpoints that are being contacted.

I've stumbled upon a problem where the app calls the API and it uses an API key. That key hasn't been shared before and I don't know how it's calculated.

Even before attempting to log-in the phone makes some requests with the key. They key is of the form  `TR6EHaaNTSFGFmMt`, with 16 characters. My problem comes here, is it randomly generated? Is it a hash of the IMEI/MAC Address? Is it possible to reverse it or know more or less how it's created? How can I know which hash function has been used?

My knowledge on cryptographic functions is still a bit limited.

Answer (score -1):

The API key is maybe just a random hard coded secret. Take a look here:
https://github.com/ikarulus/nextbike-api-reverse-engineering#obtaing-api-key